# In TD(0) with linear function approximation, why is the gradient of $\hat v(S^{\prime}, \mathbf w)$ wrt parameters $\mathbf w$ not considered?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, value-functions, function-approximation, weights, temporal-difference-methods

I am reading [these slides](http://web.archive.org/web/20210506214610/https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs234/slides/lecture5.pdf). On page 38, the update for the parameters for the linear function approximation of TD(0) is given. I have a doubt regarding this.
The cost function (RMSE) is given on page 37.

My doubt is: why is the gradient of $\hat v(S^{\prime}, \mathbf w)$ with respect to parameters $w$ not considered?

I think the parameter update should be:
$$\mathbf w \leftarrow \mathbf w +\alpha [R + \gamma \hat v(S', \mathbf w) - \hat v(S, \mathbf w)] (\nabla \hat v(S, \mathbf w)- \gamma \nabla \hat v(S', \mathbf w))$$
Instead in the material it is given as:-
$$\mathbf w \leftarrow \mathbf w +\alpha [R + \gamma \hat v(S', \mathbf w) - \hat v(S, \mathbf w)] \nabla \hat v(S, \mathbf w)$$

Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is formally known as a *semi-gradient method*.

What we would like to do is to minimize $\big(v(S) - \hat v(S, w)\big)^2$, where   $v(S)$ is the true value function. This would give the gradient descent update
\begin{align*} 
w \leftarrow w + \alpha[v(S) - \hat v(S, w)]\nabla \hat v(S, w) . \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Of course we don't have access to $v(S)$. So instead, we could use the monte carlo return (the observed, discounted, episodic return). The other option is to use a bootstraped estimate of $v(S)$, e.g.  the estimate $r + \gamma \hat v(S', w)$, which would give the update

\begin{align*} 
w \leftarrow w + \alpha[r + \gamma \hat v(S', w) - \hat v(S, w)]\nabla \hat v(S, w) \tag{2}
\end{align*}

As you correctly point out, Eq. 2 is no longer a true gradient descent method. To directly quote Sutton and Barto, section 9.3 page 165,

> This step [Eq. 1] would not be valid if a bootstrapping estimate were
> used in place of v(S). Bootstrapping methods are not in fact instances
> of true gradient descent (Barnard, 1993). They take into account the
> effect of changing the weight vector w on the estimate, but ignore its
> effect on the target. They include only a part of the gradient and,
> accordingly, we call them semi-gradient methods.

The 'estimate' here is refering to $\hat v(S, w)$, whereas the 'target' is $v(S)$ (or its approximation). Indeed the parameter update you give would be the true gradient descent update for minimizing $\big(r + \gamma \hat v(S', w) - \hat v(S, w)\big)^2$